# How to resolve midgard2 already loaded?

Tags: ubuntu, php

When running PHP on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine I get the following warning:

```
 PHP Warning:  Module 'midgard2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

This tells me exactly nothing. How could I resolve this issue?

I tried purging all components having midgard in their name and reinstalling `php5-midgard2` -- the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled `midgard2.so` twice. To find files where it's enables, try this one for apache2 :

```
grep -R "extension=midgard2" /etc/php5/apache2
```

or

```
grep -R "extension=midgard2" /etc/php5/cli
```

Make sure that there is only one line uncommented `; line` for comment

Comment: The files in my case were `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-midgard2.ini` and `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/midgard2.ini`.

Comment: Comment `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/midgard2.ini`, it's appear that now (I don't know since when), `php` extensions from `aptitude` is handled by `php5enmod` (who use `20-midgard2.ini`.